# LEFT JOIN Duplicate figures

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following tables:

`InvoiceMaster` and `InvoiceDetails` joined by `InvoiceMasterID`

`POMaster` and `POdetail` joined by `POMasterID`

`InvoiceDetails` is linked to `PODetail` via `InvDetailID`

Scenario

```
          InvMaster

  InvMasterID     InvNumber
    112233         12345


          InvDetails

  InvMasterID     InvDetailID      SalesAmt
    112233            45454           100


          POMaster

  POMasterID     OrderNumber
    525120         98765
    525121         77884          


          PODetail

  PODetailID     InvDetailID     PurchaseAmt
    525120          45454            500
    525121          45454            300




       LEFT SIDE         ----       RIGHT SIDE
-------------------------------------------------------------
InvNumber   SalesAmt     ----    OrderNumber     PurchaseAmt
-------------------------------------------------------------
  12345        100                  98765            500
  12345        100                  77884            300
```

I want everything to show on the "Left Side" and anything that links on the right side to show.

My issue is that in this scenario above I have the **Sales Amount** being duplicated.
This happens when there are 2 Right-Sides Vs 1 Left-Side

If I were to total up the `SalesAmt` it would be wrong now because it is showing `200` instead of `100`.

Is it possible to only show 100? How would I join my tables. Bearing in mind that I may have multiple tables on the Right Side not just PO as stated in this example.
Currently I'm using a mixture of a `left join` and `group by's`

Comment: You have tables InvoiceMaster and InvoiceDetails, then you say Invoice table - is that a another table not mentioned before?

Comment: Sorry when I saw invoice table I'm speak about both the invoice tables as a whole.

Comment: Can't you give us sample data for all 4 (?) tables involved, and it will be much easier to understand the problem. (Sample data that macth the expected output!)

Comment: @jarlh added more information